# foreach statements and setting variables to use outside of loop

Tags: php, mysql, loops, variables, foreach

I have created a `foreach` statement that will access a MySQL database and will display the Username and ID of each person in the database in a list -- no problem there. The button next to each person will display the ID number -- no problem there. However when I press the button it will return the value of the very last person which in this case is 30 rather than the number 1 or whatever number of the button I press.

I think this is because as the page is displayed it assigns the ID to the variable for each pass of the loop as it is being displayed.

`$ID` will be set to the last one because on displaying the page it goes through everyone in the list before finishing off at the last option, just in displaying the page. So when it comes to me pressing the button of course `$ID` will be set to 30, because it had to count up to that just so I can see it. That is the problem I'm having. When I press the button I want the `Session['id']` to be set to what ever the `$ID` is set to then, not what the `$ID` is set to after the page has finished displaying.

```
<?php
include 'connect.php';

foreach($db->query("SELECT * FROM Staff") as $row) {
    $ID = $row['id']
    Echo $row['id'];
    Echo $row['FirstName'];
    Echo $row['LastName'];
?> 


<button Class="link" id="OpenUp"><?php echo $id; $_SESSON['id'] = $id; ?></button>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Definie `$ID` before the foreach, now the `$ID` is only exists in the foreach scope. And also `$ID` is not equals `$id`. The variables are case sensitive.

Comment: Why do you use session at all? What function is activated when the button is pressed?

Answer (score 0):

Your code will always set $_SESSION['id'] to your last value.

You can start a form before the loop and use this bit of code instead of button

```
<input type="submit" name="setsessionid" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>" />
```

After that all you have to do is set the variable as $_SESSION['id'] using

```
<?php if(isset($_POST['setsessionid']) { $_SESSION['id'] = $_POST['setsessionid']; } ?>
```

Comment: The problem with using a form is that it will post to a different page. whilst I've set that up all well and good my manager wants a popup. the "OpenUp" id will on click use JavaScript to change the CSS of the page. opening a window in the centre of the page that will display results depending on which button that is pressed. Is their a way for the form to post to the same page without loading a new page?